# aligning image and text to center together and fold

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I center two items, an image and text together, and have the text fold below when re-sized?

the scenario for small is easy enough, but I having a hard time centering the text vertically on the image inline while centering the full width of the text+image horizontally.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="cover">
  <span class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing</span>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
.cover{
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
 @media (max-width:1200px) {
  .cover{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .caption {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: It works, I've only added `text-center` to `<div class="col-md-6">`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? The idea is using inline block, see the follows.

```css
p {
    text-align: center;
}

p * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    <span>text text text</span>
</p>
```

**Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4e9kro2p/

Comment: In the fiddle, it works fine, but when I have it with the rest of the styles, the text breaks instead of folding as one.